# Was Dana conscious when possessed by Zuul?

Tags: ghostbusters

Zuul was the ancient demon dog who served Gozer alongside Vinz; he terrorises and eventually captures Dana. I read that Zuul only posseses women when bringing Evil Gods to the world (according to the original movies).

My question is if Dana could have been conscious when under possession, and not remembered being forced to flirt with Peter; especially when she was ‘turned’ into a dog?

Comment: "**There is no Dana, only Zuul!!!**"

Comment: Given that [neither Dana nor Louis have any memory of what happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33415/did-the-gatekeeper-and-the-keymaster-get-intimate-in-ghostbusters#71666), there's a strong case to argue that they were unconscious during their possession (or that their consciousnesses were elsewhere at the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as clear with Dana, but Louis Tully clearly has no (or almost no) idea what happened during his possession by Vinz Clortho, the Key Master.  It is probably safe to assume that Dana's possession by Zuul worked the same way.  The two humans might have been vaguely aware of what was going on while they were possessed by the terror dogs, but they would not have been fully conscious.

(I say they *might* have been vaguely aware since, in a deleted scene, Dana is adamant that she and Louis did not have sex while they were possessed.  Whether she is reliable on this point is unclear, nor is it clear whether the deleted dialogue is considered canonical.)

Comment: Even if you consider the deleted dialogue canonical, I think it's more a case of wishful thinking than an actual memory, however vague. :-)